TypeScript using a function attribute as an array key
import { PlanificationElement } from "../../../models/dtos/PlanificationElement";
interface BaseCellRenderProps {
  cell: { data: PlanificationElement };
  col: string;
}
export const BaseCellRender: React.FC<BaseCellRenderProps> = ({ cell, col }) => {
  if (cell.data.level !== 4) {
    return <b>{cell.data[col]}</b>;
  }
  return cell.data[col];
};

this code works fine but i got this TS error:
element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PlanificationElement'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PlanificationElement'.ts(7053)
(parameter) cell: {
data: PlanificationElement;

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see what you're seeing. We'd need to see the definition of PlanificationElement before we could begin to understand what to do.

You'll want to limit col to just the properties that PlanificationElement actually has, not any string

import { PlanificationElement } from "../../../models/dtos/PlanificationElement";

interface BaseCellRenderProps {
  cell: { data: PlanificationElement };
  col: string;
}

export const BaseCellRender: React.FC<BaseCellRenderProps> = ({ cell, col }) => {
  const cellData = cell.data as { [key: string]: any };

  if (cell.data.level !== 4) {
    return <b>{cellData[col]}</b>;
  }
  return cellData[col];
};

The TypeScript error is fixed since it is claimed that the cell.data object has an index signature that permits dynamic key access.
